# Angularjs datepicker - how to set mutually dependent dates

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am working on a feature that requires me to inactivate an entity for a given period. So, I show two date pickers : 1) Starting date and 2) Ending date.

The two dates are interdependent in a manner where the starting date limits the min date for ending date and the ending date limits the max date for starting date.

```
<input type="text" ui-date="inactive.datePicker" ui-date-format="mm/dd/yy" ng-model="inactive.details.fromDate"  id="fromDate"  ng-change="error.dueDate=false"  value="inactive.details.fromDate}}"/>
<img ng-click="showFromDatePicker($event)" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../design/calendar3.gif" >


<input type="text" ui-date="inactive.datePicker" ui-date-ormat="mm/dd/yy" ng-model="inactive.details.toDate" id="toDate"  ng-change="error.dueDate=false" value="{{inactive.details.toDate}}"/>
<img ng-click="showToDatePicker($event)" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../design/calendar3.gif" >


$scope.showFromDatePicker = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.inactive.fromDatepicker = {
           max : $scope.inactive.details.toDate;
        }
        angular.element("#fromDate").focus();
    };

$scope.showToDatePicker = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.inactive.toDatepicker = {
           max : $scope.inactive.details.fromDate;
        }
        angular.element("#toDate").focus();
    };
```

But right now this piece of snippet isn't exactly working properly. The min date is setting properly but let's kind of disabling the datepicker so I couldn't select a date. Also how do I reinitialize or refresh the datepicker in AngularJS like we could do in Jquery by

```
$("#myDatepicker").datepicker("refresh");
```

Comment: Which datepicker are you using ? Doesn't seem like Angular-UI's. They have a `min-date` attribute in them.

Comment: yes they do but its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

In angular-ui-bootstrap 0.14.3 I managed to achieve this just by binding min and max to the other model. I use a wrapper directive around datepicker but it shouldn't make any difference:

```
Begin datepicker: max-date="myobject.endDate"
End datepicker: min-date="myobject.beginDate" max-date="today"
```